# How to avoid memory problems when running php mongodb aggregate group function?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, grouping

I'm running into memory problems when I try to group a list by a field.

**Input:** it's a list of items with a category and some fields:

```
{ category: "CATNAME1", field1: "value11", field2: "value21", ... },
{ category: "CATNAME2", field1: "value12", field2: "value22", ... },
{ category: "CATNAME3", field1: "value13", field2: "value23", ... },
{ category: "CATNAME4", field1: "value14", field2: "value24", ... }, ..
```

**Output:** should be a list of the categories, each with a list of the corresponding items:

```
{ category: "CATNAME1", items: [
    { field1: "value12", field2: "value22", ... },
    { field1: "value14", field2: "value24", ... }, ..
] },
{ category: "CATNAME2", items: [
    { field1: "value12", field2: "value22", ... },
    { field1: "value14", field2: "value24", ... }, ..
] },
```

**//Edit:** We tried different versions, removed all but one for better readability.

**Partial solution:**
This works for small lists, but runs out of memory when I have like 1000 categories with 1000 items each. :(

```
$cursor = $collection->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                .. some filters here ...
            ) ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$category',
                    'items' => array( '$addToSet' => array(
                        'field1' => '$field1',
                        'field2' => '$field2',
                        'field3' => '$field3',
                        'field4' => '$field4'
                    ) ) ) ) ) );
```

When I try to get the input list from the beginning, all works fine. But as soon as I try to group them somehow it fails. Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Comment: Your whole approach here is so wrong for many reasons. What are you actually trying to achieve here? A count on "category" perhaps?

Comment: Not a count, I want to list all items in a website, but with a header for each category.

Comment: As stated. You are still doing the wrong thing and for many reasons. Group and mapReduce are obsolete for this type of usage.

Comment: You do not need this $addToSet usage here, and it is very inefficient. Look at the edited content of the answer I gave.

Comment: Hmm, the problem was that with your query I got a long list of arrays with one element each. Basically like a sorted list, but everything nested one element deeper than expected.

Comment: Huh? What arrays? There are no arrays anywhere. Your question is not very clear in regards to what you want to achieve, otherwise you would have an answer by now.

Comment: Sorry, I have reworked the question, hope it is clearer now? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You seem to have "re-worked" the question quite a lot since originally and as answered you were actually asking "how" to do this and not what the "new" title is now saying. It is generally a good idea to accept the answer given and ask "another" question. The reason being the answers provided now "appear" to not answer the question even if they did at the time. I would strongly encourage you to actually ask another question, but generally what is the exact problem with the number of results being returned?

Comment: I would have accepted if the solution had worked, but it just gave me an weird array of arrays of single items, that was even worse than before. I don't think that the question itself has changed a lot, I ran into memory problems with group() and now I have the same with aggregate().

Comment: I really don't know what to say here other that there is already a long history of comments to try and get you to show something and your edits and responses are not very clear. People can only answer on the data that you supply and it works for me and likely for others as well

Comment: I made a pastebin of what happens with your solution: http://pastebin.com/j5er6RYg

Comment: And this happens with mine for large datasets: Error: localhost:27017: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

Comment: can I delete this question somehow? for me it's not leading anywhere and it's probably not helping anyone else ..

Answer (score -1):

So as stated, wrong game and even the wrong sport. Use aggregate for this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$category",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "value":  { "$first": "$value" }
    }
])
```

Which is a very simple query. The **`.group()`** function should almost be considered deprecated. And **`mapReduce`** is also not appropriate for this type of operation, it runs **much** slower than the native code interface used by **aggregate**. The **`mapReduce`** way uses a JavaScript interpreter which is many times slower in execution.

---

### EDIT

If you actually just want unique values over the collection then the statement is quite simple just as it would be in SQL:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "category": "$category",
            "name": "$name",
            "value":  "$value"
        }
    }
])
```

So that basically groups directly on the values and not on the "boundaries" and therefore produces unique values over the combination.

Comment: Could you please check my edit of the question? Aggregate seems to be the way, but I only get one result per category.

Comment: @DanielBrown Sorry that was actually by design in the response. There is another way that is more like a SQL GROUP BY response. As edited.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Does this code work for you as expected? I only get results as seen in this pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/j5er6RYg

Answer (score -1):

You schema is an almost exact copy of what people would use in a SQL environment.

Try changing your schema to

```
{
    "category": "cat1",
    "values": {
        "item1": "value1",
        "item1": "value2"
    }
 }
```

This should work fine as long as the number of different keys does not grow above 100 or 1000.

Comment: Since the data is coming from SQL, this might be true. :) Your schema is probably better, but it's a lot of categories and I need to show both the plain and the structured view, so will stick to this one if possible.

Comment: You can always use the [`unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) function from the aggregation pipeline. Like this you can use the perfect schema AND show the table view.

Comment: @hannesvdvreken Not really sure why `$unwind` has any place in this considering there is not actually an array field anywhere in the example.

Comment: O, @NeilLunn, you're right. If you would do `"values": [{'item1': 'value1'}, {...}]` it is possible.

Comment: @hannesvdvreken What I was trying to explain is that there is no actual "array" field in the example in the question. They are just all plain documents in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far and just for clarification, I was trying to get this structure:  `{ "category": "cat1", "values": [ { "name": "name1", "item1": "value1", "item1": "value2" }, { .. }, { .. }, ... ] }`

Comment: @NeilLunn No, but you could denormalize and put the rows with the same category in the same array. Like in my answer